# Need assistance with Java IntelliJ not reading my file

Tags: java, file, class, import

I need some assistance with my Java project being unable to read my file that is in the same directory as my classes. Here is the snippet:

```
private static final String FILENAME = "my_address.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    AddressBook book = new AddressBook();
    book.readFile(FILENAME);
    int choice;
    do...
```

Whenever I try to bring in my text file (my_address.txt),I receive this message...

```
my_address.txt could not be found! Exiting..
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can someone please assist me with getting my file onto my project?
[In the same file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsi4d.png)

As someone has mentioned in the comments, here is a snippet of my AddressBook portion:

```
package Animal;

public class AddressBook {
    private ArrayList<Person> people;

public AddressBook()
{
    this.people = new ArrayList<>();
}
public void readFile(String filename)
{
    Scanner fileReader;
    try
    {
        fileReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while(fileReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] data = fileReader.nextLine().trim().split(",");
            String firstName = data[0];
            String lastName = data[1];
            String address = data[2];
            String phone = data[3];
            people.add(new Person(firstName, lastName, address, phone));
        }
        fileReader.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println(filename + " could not be found! Exiting..");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to show the code for AddressBook.readFile(String filename) as this is where things go wrong

Answer (score 0):

From the image linked to in your question, it looks like you are using [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) as your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). So when you build your java source code, file *my_address.txt* gets copied to the same directory that contains the compiled class which in your case appears to be `Main`. So file *my_address.txt* should be in the same directory as file *Main.class*

The following line of code creates a path to a file.

```java
new File(filename)
```

If the value of variable `filename` is **my_address.txt** then the path to the directory containing file **my_address.txt** will be the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). If you don't know what the working directory is, the following [java] code will get it for you.

```java
String pathToWorkingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

You will find that it is **not** the same directory that contains the file *Main.class* and that's why you are getting the `FileNotFoundException`.

In your case, file *my_address.txt* is referred to as a resource and the JDK includes an [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) for retrieving resources.

Hence in order to fix your code such that it does not throw `FileNotFoundException`, either use the API for retrieving resources or move file *my_address.txt* to the working directory.

If you use the API, then the following java code shows how to create a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for reading the file. Note that I assume that class `Main` is in the same package as class `AddressBook`, which, according to the code in your question, is package `Animal`. By the way, it is recommended to adhere to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) so the name of the package should be `animal`.

```java
java.net.URL url = Main.class.getResource("my_address.txt");
if (url != null) {
    try {
        java.net.URI uri = url.toURI(); // throws URISyntaxException
        java.io.File f = new java.io.File(uri);
        java.util.Scanner fileReader = new java.util.Scanner(f); // throws FileNotFoundException
    }
    catch (java.net.URISyntaxException | java.io.FileNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else {
    // The file was not found.
}
```

The above code uses [multi catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html).

I also recommend printing the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) in the `catch` blocks in your code.